# Sliding animation to the load template

Tags: jquery, html, css

HTML:

```
<button id='btn'>Click</button>
```

Main.html:

```
<div id="main"><p>Hai I am Main..</p></div>
```

Sub.html

```
<div id="sub"><p>Hai I am sub..</p></div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on("click", "btn", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var toggler = $('#main'),
                wrapper = toggler.find('#sub');

            if(wrapper.length==0){
                toggler.load("sub.html");
            }
            else{
                toggler.load("main.html");
            }

        });
```

The template load is working fine, trying to add the sliding event to the template when it gets load. I tried `$toggler.load("sub.html").slideUp()`

The template should load with the animation slideup on button click again on button click it should slide down. How can I do this?

Comment: Your selector missing `#` where it must be `#btn`, is that your actual code? Or a typo?

Comment: try like toggler.load("main.html").slideToggle();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on("click", "#btn", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var toggler = $('#main'),
                wrapper = toggler.find('#sub');
            if(wrapper.length==0){
                toggler.load("sub.html").slideToggle();
            }
            else{
                toggler.load("main.html").slideToggle();
            }
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/y9avm/